# GWT ImageResource background-position

Tags: gwt, uibinder, clientbundle

I'm attempting to use a single .png as a button with a hover effect (a la [this](http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/create-a-button-with-hover-and-active-states-using-css-sprites/)) in GWT using UIBinder but am having a tough time.

Here's my ui.xml file:

```
<ui:with field="functionResources" type="myapp.client.application.functions.FunctionResources"/>

<ui:style>

    .clickableIcon{
        cursor: hand;
        cursor: pointer;            
    }

    .clickableIcon:hover{
        cursor: hand;
        cursor: pointer;                        
        background-position: 0 -76px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:VerticalPanel ui:field="buttonPanel">
    <g:Image ui:field="survivalIcon" debugId="survivalIcon" width="76px" resource="{functionResources.survivalIcon}" styleName="{style.clickableIcon}"/>

</g:VerticalPanel>
```

I'm able to get the .png bundled and displayed in the browser just fine. However, my :hover CSS isn't working as desired. It will, indeed, display a blue border around the image when I hover, so I know the CSS is working, but the image doesn't change.

It looks like the bundled image is overriding the background-position property as `0 0` in the element style itself, which negates my class-level styling. Is there any way to tell GWT not to set the background-position for a bundled ImageResource? Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that I was able to get this working with an `!important` declaration, but that's a bit hackish for my tastes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the poor documentation I've found on the web, you cannot override `g:Image`'s background-position property.

An alternative would be to use GWT's sprite system to generate a background-image, on which you will be able to override the `background-position` property.

For example,

```
<div class="{functionResources.style.survivalIcon} {style.clickableIcon}"/>
```

where `FunctionResources` would have:

```
public interface FunctionResources extends ClientBundle {
    public interface Style extends CssResource {
        String survivalIcon();
    }

    Style style();
    ImageResource survivalIconImage();
}
```

and, in a separate CSS file named `style.css`, you'd have:

```
@sprite .survivalIcon {
    gwt-image: "survivalIconImage";
}
```

This will generate a div, with the background-image you wanted. You will be able to modify the div's `background-position` property at will.

Of course, this method can be applied to any DOM element that supports background-image.